# csv didn't work on translate store language label in magento frontend

Tags: frontend, language, translate

getStores()) > 1): ?>

```
<?php $id = $block->getIdModifier() ? '-' . $block->getIdModifier() : '' ?>
<div class="switcher language switcher-language" data-ui-id="language-switcher"
     id="switcher-language<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
     echo $id ?>">
    <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Language') ?></span></strong>
    <div class="switcher-content">
        <div class="action-switcher" id="switcher-language-trigger<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $id ?>">
            <div class="heading-switcher view-<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentStoreCode()) ?>"
                 style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                 echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/flags/flag_' . $block->getCurrentStoreCode() . '.svg') ?>');">
                <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreName()) ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown-switcher">
            <ul class="list-item">
                <?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
                    <?php if ($_lang->getId() != $block->getCurrentStoreId()): ?>
                        <li class="view-<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()); ?> switcher-option">
                            <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            echo $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang); ?>'>
                            <span style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/flags/flag_' . $_lang->getCode() . '.svg') ?>');"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What csv? Where is it located? (To me) it's pretty unclear what you are trying to accomplish and what were the steps you took so far.

Comment: my apologies...when you’re on the English store it will appears English/French but when you are on the French store it will appear Anglais/Francais. I have "English","Anglais" and "French","Francais" inside the  fr_FR.csv.  but it still didn't get translate.  Please see this picture  https://prnt.sc/25uwgix